# matlab: Addressing multiple rows in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

Suppose that "r" is a multidimensional array of size [N, N, M] and "tab" is a table of size [N] with values 1..N (e.g. take "tab=randperm(N)"). I'm looking for efficient way to do the following:

```
    c = ones(M, 1);
    for k=1:N
        c = c .* squeeze(r(tab(k),k,:));
    end
```

I'd like to do that in matrix notation, using prod, but didn't find a solution, as "r(tab(1:N),1:N,:)" returns an NxNxM matrix rather than N rows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @DanielR: From question text: "and tab is a table of size [N] with values 1..N"

Comment: @RobertP. is correct; e.g. take "tab=randperm(N)"

Comment: @UriCohen: First reading, I expected some data of class `table`, which was recently introduced to matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) across dimensions 1, 2; [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to replicate along dimension 3; and then [`prod`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/prod.html):

```
c = prod(r(bsxfun(@plus, sub2ind([N N], tab, 1:N).', (0:M-1)*N^2))).';
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the syntax: is the ".'" a valid syntax?

Comment: You could remove that final `.'` if you don't mind obtaining a row vector instead of a line vector

Answer (score 0):

```
%% example data
M=3;
N=4;
r=rand(N,N,M);
tab=randperm(N);

%% original code    

c = ones(M, 1);
for k=1:N
    c = c .* squeeze(r(tab(k),k,:));
end

%% Code is equivalent to:

% rh=r(tab,:,:);
% c2 = ones(M, 1);
% for k=1:N
%     c2 = c2 .* squeeze(rh(k,k,:));
% end
% assert(all(c2==c));

%% second solution: Use sub2ind to index
rh=r(tab,:,:);

ix=sub2ind(size(rh),ceil(1/M:1/M:N),ceil(1/M:1/M:N),repmat(1:M,1,N));
rh2=rh(ix);
rh3=reshape(rh2,M,N);
c3=prod(rh3,2);
assert(all(c3==c));
```